# Populate ListView (With 3 TextViews) From Database

Tags: android, listview

I have defined my DatabaseHelper class and can query the database. I would like to populate 3 columns from the database (name, venue, date) to a `ListView` with 3 `TextViews`, somehow I can't get my `CustomAdapter` right.

This is the error:

`CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, myItems_name, myItems_venue, myItems_date);`

Please see full code below:

```
    public class ActivityLayout extends MainActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    List<String> myItems_name;
    List<String> myItems_venue;
    List<String> myItems_date;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);


    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, myItems_name, myItems_venue, myItems_date);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textNameSingle);
        Toast.makeText(this,tv.getText()+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    DatabaseHelper dbHeplper;

    private Context context;
    private List<String> myItems_name = dbHeplper.getDBData();
    private List<String> myItems_venue = dbHeplper.getDBData();
    private List<String> myItems_date = dbHeplper.getDBData();

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resources,  List<String> objects) {
        super(context, resources, objects);

        this.context=context;
        this.myItems_name=objects;
        this.myItems_venue=objects;
        this.myItems_date=objects;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View row=convertView;
        if(row==null)
        {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout_single, parent, false);       
        }
        TextView txtArtist = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textNameSingle);
        TextView txtVenue = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textVenueSingle);
        TextView txtDate = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textDateSingle);

        txtArtist.setText(myItems_name[position]);
        txtVenue.setText(myItems_venue[position]);
        txtDate.setText(myItems_date[position]);

        return row; 
    }   
}
```

Update: #01

@ρяσѕρєя K - I have changed my Activity and Custom Adapter as follows: (problem still exists):

Activity:

```
    public class ActivityLayout extends MainActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {


    List<String> myItems_name;
    List<String> myItems_venue;
    List<String> myItems_date;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);


    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.my_layout, myItems_name, myItems_venue, myItems_date);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Adapter:

```
    class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    DatabaseHelper dbHeplper;

    private Context context;
    private List<String> myItems_name = dbHeplper.getDBData();
    private List<String> myItems_venue = dbHeplper.getDBData();
    private List<String> myItems_date = dbHeplper.getDBData()

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resources,  
            List<String> myItems_name,
        List<String> myItems_venue,
        List<String> myItems_date) {

        super(context, resources, myItems_name);

        this.context=context;
        this.myItems_name=myItems_name;
        this.myItems_venue=myItems_venue;
        this.myItems_date=myItems_date;
    }
```

Comment: What is the error? Please state clearly, showing Logcat if it's a crash.

Comment: `@Override
    public int getCount() {
        return size_of_your_array;
    }` just try this and see if you got your list view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

> CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, myItems_name,
>   myItems_venue, myItems_date);

Line causing issue because no constructor available in `CustomAdapter` which takes 4 parameters

Add   two parameters to CustomAdapter class constructor for getting `myItems_name` and `myItems_venue`:

```
 public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resources, 
                             List<String> myItems_name,
                             List<String> myItems_venue,
                             List<String> myItems_date) {
        super(context, resources, myItems_name);

         //.... your code here
    }
```

Also pass layout it which want to use for ListView row as second parameter to `CustomAdapter` class constructor :

```
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,R.layout.my_layout_single, 
                                myItems_name, myItems_venue, myItems_date);
```

Comment: @TwoStarII: now what problem getting?

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K

Error: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Comment: @TwoStarII: Show updated code where starting Activity?

Answer (score 1):

you need to initialize these values:

```
List<String> myItems_name;
List<String> myItems_venue;
List<String> myItems_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

@ρяσѕρєя K

Thanks your answer has been selected, the error is no longer now. I added 
dbHeplper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext()); under onCreate. Thank you for your help sir.

@ρяσѕρєя K (see update code below)
Update Code:

```
    public class ActivityLayout extends MainActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    DatabaseHelper dbHeplper;

    ListView list;
    List<String> myItems_name;
    List<String> myItems_venue;
    List<String> myItems_date;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);

    dbHeplper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());

    myItems_name = dbHeplper.getDBName();
    myItems_venue = dbHeplper.getDBVenue();
    myItems_date = dbHeplper.getDBDate();

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, myItems_name, myItems_venue, myItems_date);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }
```